# polymorphic_path not generating correct path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, polymorphic-associations

I am trying to user a rails method called polymorphic_path but I am getting the wrong url.
My polymorphic association is with Students and Landlords who are both Users through userable.

Here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :userable, polymorphic: true
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :userable
end

class Landlord < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :userable
end
```

I have a variable called current_user holding the User object. The following line:

```
<%= link_to "Profile", polymorphic_path(current_user) %>
```

gives me the url "users/22" instead of returning the Student/Landlord url.

Here is my routes.rb file if that helps..

```
resources :users
resources :students
resources :landlords
```

Where am I going wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it! And the solution was painfully obvious...

```
<%= link_to "Profile", polymorphic_path(current_user.userable) %>
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_polymorphic_path(current_user.userable) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not sure if polymorphic_path should work they way You using it, home brewed alternative

```
# application_controller.rb    
helper_method :current_profile, :path_to_profile
def current_profile
   @current_profile ||= current_user.userable
end

def path_to_profile
   send("#{current_profile.class.downcase}_path", current_profile)
end
```

With few additional lines You can extend it to work with other methods too, not only show.

Comment: Looks like the most elegant of non elegant solutions... I just thought that that was what polymorphic_path was meant for. Thanks for the answer though.